# "Does not revealed"

Tags: grammar, past-tense, time

I've found this sentence, and thought it has a bad grammar:

> Audiometry, abdominal ultrasonography, echocardiography **does not**
>   **revealed** other abnormalities.

But there are many usages of this phrase on Internet, that I'm confused now.

I thought it should be maybe like this

> Audiometry, abdominal ultrasonography, echocardiography **hasn't revealed**
>    other abnormalities.

or maybe

> Audiometry, abdominal ultrasonography, echocardiography **didn't reveal**
>    other abnormalities ( + when).

Could you please explain it to me?  Thanks.

Comment: Could you link another usage?

Comment: http://europepmc.org/articles/PMC3841637

Comment: that was the example you used in the question

Comment: @Slepz But they didn't cite it, as usually required for a quality question. I'm not the OP.

Comment: @Gandalf I guess but I was looking for one of the other many usages he said there were

Comment: @Slepz I found [one more](https://books.google.com.gt/books?id=t45nAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT222&dq=%22+does+not+revealed+%22&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22%20does%20not%20revealed%20%22&f=false) , but as we say in Spanish  _nada que ver_ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's incorrect, though perhaps it's a common error (I haven't noticed it myself). "Revealed" is a past participle. You could use it with the present perfect or past perfect tense, e.g. "has not revealed" or "had not revealed." But you cannot use it with "does" or "did." In that case, as you noted, the correct usage is "does not reveal" or "did not reveal."

Comment: _Revealed_ is a past tense as well as participle, being a regular verb. The sentence is incorrect for having double past tense markers. As the rest of the text was written using simple past, the sentence should have been in past tense.